# get combination from multiple PHP arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I am new in PHP.I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0,1
    [1] => 0,2
    [2] => 0,3
)

Array
(
    [0] => 0,1
    [1] => 0,2
    [2] => 0,3
)

Array
(
    [0] => 0,1
    [1] => 0,2
    [2] => 0,3
)

Array
(
    [0] => 0,1
    [1] => 0,2
    [2] => 0,3
)
```

I want combination like this:

```
(0,1),(0,1),(0,1),(0,1)
(0,1),(0,2),(0,2),(0,2)
(0,1),(0,3),(0,3),(0,3)
(0,2),(0,1),(0,1),(0,1)
(0,2),(0,2),(0,2),(0,2)
(0,3),(0,1),(0,1),(0,1)
(0,3),(0,2),(0,2),(0,2)
(0,3),(0,3),(0,3),(0,3)
```

How can I achieve this? The answer I'm looking for should not include all the possible combination.

Comment: And do you have any code trying to achiev this?

Comment: SO is not a coding service, please try it by your self, and if you have any issues, be sure, we will help you :)

Comment: its looks like he is doing his homework  :) Maybe a math problem: matrix multiplier or sum etc